# Executing reset method before each test in Spec2

Tags: scala, testing, specs2

I have a defined test method chain in test class using Spec2:

```
def is =
  "EntriesServlet with logged user" ^
  "POST / request should update entry that user owns" ! updateExistingEntryThatLoggedUserOwns ^
  "POST / request should not update non existing entry" ! notUpdateNonExistingEntry ^
  "POST / request should not update non owner entry" ! notAllowToUpdateNotOwnedEntry
end
```

and in these methods I am checking if defined mock were called. But I need to recreate one mock so I could count invocations only for one method not globally.

So what I need is a way to seamlessly define method let's say:

```
 def prepareMocks = {
   serviceMock = mock[MyService]
 }
```

that will be executed before each test method so I have clean mock ready before checking my assertions.

I tried with traits `BeforeEach` and `BeforeExample` from Spec2 but they are not what I am looking for.

Comment: You create a context to provide the test fixture of the mutable state. The user guide [describes](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Isolation_1) how to do this for acceptance tests. I've only used unit specifications, so good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case classes to instantiate your mocks and isolate them from other examples being executed at the same time:

```
import org.specs2._
import specification._
import mock._

class MySpec extends Specification { def is =
  "EntriesServlet with logged user" ^
    "POST / request should update entry that user owns" !        c().updateExistingEntryThatLoggedUserOwns ^
    "POST / request should not update non existing entry" ! c().notUpdateNonExistingEntry ^
    "POST / request should not update non owner entry" ! c().notAllowToUpdateNotOwnedEntry ^
  end

  trait MyService
  case class c() extends Mockito {
    val service = mock[MyService]

    def updateExistingEntryThatLoggedUserOwns = service must not beNull
    def notUpdateNonExistingEntry = ok
    def notAllowToUpdateNotOwnedEntry = ok
  }
}

// here's a similar solution using standardised group names which is a 1.12.3 feature

class MySpec extends Specification { def is =
  "EntriesServlet with logged user" ^
    "POST / request should update entry that user owns"   ! g1().e1 ^
    "POST / request should not update non existing entry" ! g1().e2 ^
    "POST / request should not update non owner entry"    ! g1().e3 ^
  end

  trait MyService
  "POST requests" - new g1 with Mockito {
    val service = mock[MyService]

    e1 := { service must not beNull }
    e2 := ok
    e3 := ok
  }
}
```